# Iterating over dataframes with different attributes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to understand how to properly iterate over different dataframes having slightly different attributes (like column names) in a `for` loop.

In particular what I want to do exactly is training a Machine Learning model on each single dataset and using the other as a test set.

Consider that I have two dataframes `df1`, `df2`: what I do initially is appending them into a list:

```
my_list = [df1, df2]
```

but then I am not sure how to properly iterate over these objects as they have different attributes. For example I would like to exclude the 'target' column variable in turn but as I said it is called differently in `df1, df2`. Given that, for example the names are 'target1' and 'target2' respectively, What I'm trying to do is like:

```
for df in my_list:

  if 'target1' in df.columns:
    X = df.drop('target1', axis=1)
    model.fit(X,target1)

  ...
```

But I'm not sure it is the right way..

EDIT: ok these are the outputs for `df1.head(), df2.head()` (I just make an example here cause original data is confidential).

I'm working on a chemical dataset and as you can see they are pretty similar execpt for a few columns that are named differently (Temperature and target).

> df1.head()

```
Temperature     feat_1       feat_2      feat_3       target1
   300            2.4          1.2         2.4          1.5
   298            3.2          1.5         5.7          3.4
   300            2.4          1.2         2.4          1.5
   298            1.6          1.5         3.2          3.4
   298            3.2          1.5         2.4          1.4
```

> df2.head()

```
  Temp           feat_1       feat_2      feat_3       target2
   298            3.4          1.2         3.4          2.5
   298            6.2          1.5         4.7          3.4
   300            2.4          3.3         2.4          4.5
   298            4.6          2.5         9.2          3.4
   298            3.2          1.5         5.4          6.4
```

So for each of these two datasets I would like, in turn, to train a model on an entire one and testing on the other and vice-versa, everything done in a for loop.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df1.head(5)` and `df2.head(5)` and the expected outcome, please?

Comment: I've updated the post with additional details, let me know if you need any other information, and many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you columns are ordered whatever their name, use `np.concatenate`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = np.concatenate([df1, df2])
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(X, y, train_size=len(df1), test_size=len(df2))

# From here, create your pipeline.
```